# Do we say "he is swimming in / on the river / sea"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> [riv‧er](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/river) /ˈrɪvə $ -ər/ ●●● S2 W2 noun [countable]     1 a natural and
>   continuous flow of water in a long line across a country into the sea
>   → stream
>
> the Mississippi River
>
> the River Thames
>
> **on a river**
>
> There were several boats on the river.
>
> along a river
>
> We went for a walk along the river.
>
> up/down (a) river
>
> a ship sailing up river
>
> They drifted slowly down river.
>
> across a river
>
> a bridge across the river

---

> GRAMMAR: Patterns with river
>
> **in the river** • You use in the river to
>   talk about things that happen in the water:
>
> In summer we swim in the river.
>
> There was something floating in the river.
>
> **on the river** • You use on the river to talk about things that happen
>   on the surface of a river or very close to the edge of a river:
>
> We went boating on the river.
>
> There’s a nice pub on the river.

---

> GRAMMAR: [Patterns with sea](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sea)
>
> **in the sea**
>
> • You use **in the sea** to talk about things that happen in the
>   water:
>
> We paddled in the sea.
>
> Whales are mammals that live in the sea.
>
> **on the sea**
>
> • You use **on the sea** to talk about things that happen on the
>   surface of the water:
>
> The boat floated on the calm sea.
>
> **by the sea**
>
> • You use by the sea to talk about things that are on the land near
>   the sea: They live in a cottage by the sea.

---

The dictionary says "**The boat floated on the calm sea.**" but also says "**There was something floating in the river.**"

My question is that, regarding to **our swimming technique**, sometimes we swim completely under the surface of the sea/ river (not diving though). In this case, do we say "**we are swimming in the sea / river**".?

Other times, we try to float our body on the surface of the sea/ river. In this case, do we say "**we are swimming on the sea / river**".?

Comment: It's always swimming *in* the water. Contrast a ship *on* the water, a submarine *in* the water.  (Perhaps because we're entirely in the water, i.e. have approximately neutral buoyancy... but the true explanation may be over my head.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This is a sufficient answer, you might consider reposting it as such.

Comment: @JKreft, as you suggest, it's moved to an answer, and I'll delete the comments if it's accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's always swimming in the water. Contrast a ship on the water, a submarine in the water. (Perhaps because we're entirely in the water, i.e. have approximately neutral buoyancy... but the true explanation may be over my head.)